# sudo and chpasswd on one line

Tags: bash, ssh, passwords, sudo

I need connect to server via `ssh` and change users' passwords without typing `ssh` or `sudo password`.

I found some example but I cannot complete one command.

I found this command for ssh connection without typing password and running `sudo` command for delete user:

```
sshpass -p $admin_password ssh -t $admin@$server "echo $admin_password | sudo -S /usr/sbin/userdel -r $usr"
```

then I found command for change users password:

```
echo "$usr:$password" | sudo -S /usr/sbin/chpasswd;
```

Finaly, I want something like this:

```
sshpass -p $admin_password ssh -t $admin@$server "echo $admin_password | sudo -S echo "$usr:$password" | sudo -S /usr/sbin/chpasswd;"
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that command line arguments are public on Unix systems? This means that everybody who can display a process list can read the passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually going to require 2 things. The command to change a password remotely for a user:

```
ssh remoteserver 'echo -e "passwdofuser\npasswdofuser" | passwd username'
```

In order to do that you probably need to be root, or in the sudo config, have "passwd" NOT require a password for your user to run.

```
visudo
```

Edit the file:

```
Cmnd_Alias      MYPASSWD = /usr/bin/passwd
yourusername ALL = NOPASSWD: MYPASSWD
```

That should allow you to ssh in and not have to use a password to run the passwd command.